# Why would this URL fail in Swift, it used to pass

Tags: swift, url

Curious if anyone knows if the URL parser in swift has changed.  I have a string URL that has worked in the past that stopped recently.

```
import UIKit

var greeting = "https://foo.foo.com/ddm/trackimp/N61.foo.COM/B;gdpr=${GDPR};"
let u = URL(string: greeting)
```

The issue appears to be the { and } in the URL.  I do see these listed as unsafe because backend systems may modify them.  My issue is that then loading into a URL it fails.

Comment: Percent escape them?

Comment: A good example how to misuse the **path** portion of an URL. The semicolon and the dollar sign are reserved characters. Create the URL with `URLComponents(string: greeting)` and see what you get. Basically any URL with other characters as alphanumeric, hyphen, underscore, period and tilde should **always** be encoded.

Comment: The `$` is also a "reserved" character in RFC 2396, and `{`/`}` are marked "unwise". http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html IDK if anything changed about Foundation's `URL` parser, but this was never a sound URL, in the first place

Comment: The URL parser has been very stable for years. It's hard to imagine that it's changed. What version of Swift or Objective-C accepted this URL? Swift Fiddle back to 3.0 (the earliest version that had URL) return nil. https://swiftfiddle.com/befxgz2wg5dczcif735m7zveaq